# apache connection was reset while the page was loading on windows 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, apache-2.4, firefox

I'm running a php script in windows 2008 server using xampp server, the script works normaly until I check some pages,it start loading I get this error in firefox :

> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a
>   few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your
>   computer's network connection. If your computer or network is
>   protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted
>   to access the Web

.

When I check the php logs I get nothing, in apache logs I always find this after getting the problem:

```
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:02.076599 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH00428: Parent: child process 3048 exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:08.144999 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:08.878199 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.5.24 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:08.878199 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jan 28 2015 16:48:40
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:08.878199 2015] [core:notice] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:08.909399 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3868:tid 336] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3736
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:10.157399 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3736:tid 268] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:10.469399 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 3736:tid 268] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 12 11:37:10.609799 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3736:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

I disabled the firewall, I change the port, I increase memory limit, without any result.
I do a backup of the script and I moved it to my laptop running with windows 7, the problem disapear and the script sart working normaly.

So is this problem causes by apache? and how I can fix it?

**After many tests, I found that happens only in firefox browser and it's works normaly in google chrome, I cleared all cache and history in firefox but it's not working.I don't know what is the problem exactly but I'm woking now with chrome and I ignored firefox.Any suggestion will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

If you have any opcode caching on like APC or one of the ones listed on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators, you could try disabling that.  If I recall correctly, I've run into similar issues due to APC.

Comment: I I searched didn't find any cache module in this list, just i found those LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so

Comment: This doesn't really get to the cause of your problem, but if you wanted, you could try uninstalling XAMPP and installing WampServer instead just to see if that somehow fixes it (maybe it has different default settings or modules loaded).

Comment: I tried installing wamp, the problem still exist, I already installed xampp and wamp in windows 7 It works normaly. I still get the problem only in windows 2008 server .

Comment: Try disabling every possible extension you can get by without and see if you can get it to go away and then if so, narrow it down to which extension was causing the problem.  Another thing you could try would be to use the 32 bit install instead of the 64 bit one (unless you need more than 4GB of RAM to be used by the web server which you certainly may want).

Comment: After many tests, I found that  happens only in firefox browser and it's works normaly in google chrome, I cleared all cache and history in firefox but it's not working.I don't know what is the problem exactly but I'm woking now with chrome and I Ignored firefox.Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thank you